# Htaccess rewrite rules based on 3rd word/phrase after slashes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this page on my domain: `http://www.domain.com/bizpage/5345`

The number at the end represents an ID of a business page.

I need an htaccess rule that takes everything that is built like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/bla/bla/5346
```

And redirect it to `http://www.domain.com/bizpage/5345`

Actually ignoring the 2 "bla" (that can have any text in them) and serve the page on bizpage/id.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/bizpage/\d+/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule /(\d+)/?$ /bizpage/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks! can you please explain it?

Comment: This regex: `/(\d+)/?$` will always match last set of numbers after last `/` in a URI. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/bizpage/\d+/?$` is a negative condition that makes sure URI is already not `/bizpage/<number>`. If conditions are true then rule redirects to `/bizpage/<number>`.